# Load multiple data from database with ajax and slickAdd them to existing Slick on success, but only once

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, slick.js

so I'm using Slick Carousel and I'm showing in it a list of products from my database limited to 24 for performance reasons. But I need to show all of them, so I made a function that ajax loads another 24 products everytime the user is 2 slides before the end and add them with slickAdd function to the existing Slick. Everything is working great but it takes a few seconds till it gets added because the slickAdd function runs for each new product. So I wanted to ask if there is a way to select all the 24 new products, and add them only once with the slickAdd function.

This is my current code

```
$('.demo').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){

    var komponent = $(".komponent-container.active").attr("id");

    var slideCount = slick.slideCount-6;

    console.log(slick.slideCount);

    if(nextSlide == slideCount){
        console.log("loadmore");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/project/public/konfigurator",
            data: {id: komponent, from_column: slick.slideCount, requestid: "load_more"},
            dataType: "json",

            success: function (data) {

                var data_parser = JSON.parse(data)[0];

                if (data_parser.length > 0) {

                    for (i = 0; i < data_parser.length; i++) {
                        var produkt_nazov = 0;
                        if (data_parser[i].produkt.length > 45) {
                            produkt_nazov = data_parser[i].produkt.substring(0, 45) + "...";
                        } else {
                            produkt_nazov = data_parser[i].produkt;
                        }

                        $('.demo').slick('slickAdd', '<div><div><div class="item-container"><div class="container-wrapper"><div class="produkt-container"><div class="item-left"><div class="item-image-wrapper"><img draggable="false" id="produkt-img" src="img/konfigurator/'+komponent+'/' + data_parser[i].produkt + '/1.jpg" alt="" /></div><div class="cena">' + data_parser[i].cena + ' €</div></div><div class="item-right"><div class="item-info"><span class="item-title">' + produkt_nazov + '</span><span class="item-description"><span>Výrobca čipu - ' + data_parser[i].vyrobca_cipu + '</span><span>Veľkosť pamäte - ' + data_parser[i].vram_size + '</span><span>Typ pamäte - ' + data_parser[i].vram_type + '</span><span>Frekvencia jadra - ' + data_parser[i].gpu_memory_clockrate + '</span></span></div><div class="spodna-cast"><div class="action-buttons"><a class="detail-button">Detail</a><a class="add-button">Vybrať</a></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>');
                        console.log("add");

                    }
                }
            },

            error: function (result) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And sorry if there is any gramatical mistakes, english is not my first language.

I tried to move the SlickAdd function outside the for(), but it added only 1 product to the Slick.

Comment: Can you show also how you put it out of for loop? I would expect having a helper variable holding generated code from for loop and then adding it with single slick call to work.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just figured it out but I will leave a solution here so maybe someone else will find it helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, leaving it here for others.

```js
var html = '';
for (i = 0; i < data_parser.length; i++) {
    var produkt_nazov = 0;
    if (data_parser[i].produkt.length > 45) {
        produkt_nazov = data_parser[i].produkt.substring(0, 45) + "...";
    } else {
        produkt_nazov = data_parser[i].produkt;
    }

    html += '<div><div><div class="item-container"><div class="container-wrapper"><div class="produkt-container"><div class="item-left"><div class="item-image-wrapper"><img draggable="false" id="produkt-img" src="img/konfigurator/' + komponent + '/' + data_parser[i].produkt + '/1.jpg" alt="" /></div><div class="cena">' + data_parser[i].cena + ' €</div></div><div class="item-right"><div class="item-info"><span class="item-title">' + produkt_nazov + '</span><span class="item-description"><span>Výrobca čipu - ' + data_parser[i].vyrobca_cipu + '</span><span>Veľkosť pamäte - ' + data_parser[i].vram_size + '</span><span>Typ pamäte - ' + data_parser[i].vram_type + '</span><span>Frekvencia jadra - ' + data_parser[i].gpu_memory_clockrate + '</span></span></div><div class="spodna-cast"><div class="action-buttons"><a class="detail-button">Detail</a><a class="add-button">Vybrať</a></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>';
}

$(".demo").slick('slickAdd', html);
console.log("add");
```

Comment: Here is a short fiddle demo if useful to anyone: https://jsfiddle.net/uyjp16dt/

Comment: One more question if I may ask. When the slicks add "in the background", the slick container moves a little bit. Do you know what could be causing this and how to prevent it?